# How to prepend local storage item to function call using Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage

I have an object constructor which contains variables and a function/method(?). I have several objects, each of which is called using the following (ID and item number change for each):

```
document.getElementById("item1").addEventListener("click", item1.apply);
```

The object name and ID are the same, this value is also added to local storage when the function is run. In theory, I want to grab that value and use it to generate/run the same function (as was called onclick) when the page reloads.

It sounds simple enough and I thought concatenation might do it. I can do [value] + [.apply();] to get "item1.apply();" in the console, but I can't get the browser to recognise/run it as a function.

Before this is marked as a duplicate question re creating dynamic functions, etc - most of the threads I've found seem a lot more complicated than I need. I have tried to work with them, but am getting nowhere. I haven't included more code, because I didn't want to complicate what seems like a relatively simple problem; onload get value, add to function call, run. Maybe there's a simple solution I'm not seeing (being newbie an' all)?

If not, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction, as I'm proper stuck...

Thanks in advance!

Working code:

```
var itemsArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
var currentItem = localStorage.getItem("current", this.value);

if(localStorage.getItem("current") !== null) { // check if local storage item exists

function isMatch(value, index, array) { // run current item thru isMatch 
return value == currentItem; // check if returned value matches currentItem
}   

var result = itemsArray.filter(isMatch); // this will be the matching item in itemsArray

window[result]["applyIt"](); // use the result to concatenate function call
console.log("show me: " + result[0]); // create a string with it
};
```

Comment: Group the `itemN` in an object and access the one you need using a key: `var items = {"item1": item1, "item2": item2, ...};` and then use `items` like: `items["item1"].apply`.

Comment: I've put one option as an answer. Provide some basic code [mcve] so we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me!!

Funny enough, I already had an items array that I was using to check if the item retrieved was valid (don't know if it's strictly necessary, but it seemed like a good idea). I hadn't thought about using it to populate the function call, so that was a helpful reminder. Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work (can share  non-working bits if you like?).  So moved onto Mouser's solution, which worked. I'll edit my original question to show the result and if you have any further comments, feel free to share.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your question you can try to do this:

```
window[value][apply]();
```

In you case:

```
window["item1"]["apply"]()
```

Where `item1` is a function in the global scope and `apply` is simply `apply`.

Comment: Assuming the variables are global. What if they aren't?

Comment: You are right to assume otherwise, however then you need the object's name. Eventually you'll get back to window.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, between you and Ibrahim, I was able to get it working! Using your suggestion, I was able to concatenate the function call, exactly as I was trying to do (added above). Awesome!  I'm not sure why window["item"]... worked but items["item1"]... didn't as the variables are global, as per your assumption. Or at least I think they are 
- they're not held within a function or anything. Maybe you or @ibrahim can explain/link a thread?

Thanks again, so helpful!

Comment: I was trying to be good and move all my own js code into it's own external js file, so it's easier to debug and so I don't mess up any of the existing code. However, now the above fix doesn't work...

I thought Mouser's solution would still work as it's referencing window, but it doesn't. How can I make everything work from a single external js file (maybe this should be a new question...)? I've tried putting it 'loose' in the js file, ie not within a function or object, and I've tried putting it all inside a function and calling it on window or page load, but nothing...

Any suggestions?